# Three.js webgl_loader_scene .obj + .mtl

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to do something like [loader_scene](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_scene) but I have to load .obj + .mtl file. And I am not able to convert it to .js format. Can I do it? And was [test_scene.js](http://threejs.org/examples/scenes/test_scene.js) generated or it was written by hands?

Comment: Look in the examples folder at the OBJMTLLoader fuction.

Comment: It loads just one file. I'm interested in loading multiple files of multiple formats

Comment: No you can call it multiple times as with any other loader. One per file/model.